# How to build GDAL with PDF support?

Tags: gdal, pdf, windows

I've built GDAL so many times but this time I want to add Geospatial PDF reading capability. First I built PoDoFo, but found out that Poppler is better. I found out that Win-KDE contains prebuilt binaries and libraries of Poppler. I installed KDE and modified nmake.opt as follows:

```
POPPLER_ENABLED = YES
POPPLER_CFLAGS = -Ie:/kde/include -Ie:/kde/include/poppler
POPPLER_HAS_OPTCONTENT = YES
POPPLER_BASE_STREAM_HAS_TWO_ARGS = YES
POPPLER_0_20_OR_LATER = YES
POPPLER_0_23_OR_LATER = YES
POPPLER_LIBS = D:\KDE\lib\poppler-cpp.lib D:\KDE\lib\freetype.lib D:\KDE\lib\lcms-1.lib advapi32.lib gdi32.lib
```

nmake (vc120 - VS2013) resulted without any errors. Then I copied following files to my bin dir:

```
freetype.dll
iconv.dll
JPEG.dll
lcms-1.dll
lcms2.dll (Dependency Walker found dependency)
openjpeg.dll
pdftoppm.exe
poppler-cpp.dll
tiff3.dll
zlib.dll
```

Now GDAL is unable to open PDF files. gdalinfo results in "unknown format". What do you think is wrong?

Comment: What does the list of supported formats say for your compiled result? You might like to try pdfium if you're building a newer GDAL version.

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html): "*libpoppler itself must have been configured with --enable-xpdf-headers*". Are you sure libpoppler has been compiled against the xpdf C++ headers?